# How to handle different users in different environments

Tags: java, selenium, properties, cucumber, ui-automation

For a login page automation, a user need to enter user id, security answer and password. Different environment have different users. For example, users for qa and dev environments have different user id, security answer and password. So how to handle user information properly in the automation test? We can store all the properties in the properties file, any other better solutions?

Comment: Properties files is a good approach

Comment: are you talking about the same step using different credentials to run a scenario in sevearl different environments, or different steps running different scenarios for different types of users in a single environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Data Driven Framework` automation test. Collect your data input in external file like `excel` `csv`, and read the data with the many libraries available online, maybe this link will help you find a solution :

- [Read excel file with Apache POI](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/data-driven-framework-selenium-apache-poi/)

[image: Excel data]

- [Read csv file](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/)

[image: Csv data]